# how android can detect the proximity location of the beacon

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, beacon, android-studio-2.3, estimote

I am developing an apps for detecting estimote beacon in range using android studio 2.3.2.

I just want to make it clear and understand, that actually in order to detect and get the proximity location of the estimote beacon using android apps, we just have to include the permission of Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE)  in android studio and run the apps for testing. Do guide and correct me if i am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You must obtain both BLUETOOTH_ADMIN and COARSE_LOCATION permissions to scan for beacons on Android 6+.  The latter permission is considered dangerous, so it requires prompting the user at runtime in your app in addition to adding the permission to the AndroidManifest.xml.

You can read more about how to prompt for the location permission here:

http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/requesting_permission.html

Comment: Thanks for your response. Okay so that means, if i have include the BLUETOOTH_ADMIN and COARSE_LOCATION permissions, I can run my apps to scan for proximity estimote beacon?

Comment: Correct.  Once these permissions are properly obtained you can do that.

Comment: Mr. David, what happen when @override syntax have straight line on it

Comment: That means the method you are overriding does not exist on the base class.  The base class should be a type of Activity.